# How to cache a complex object such as Map<String, List<Car>> in a Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

My spring boot app has **many** complex objects of type `Map<String, List<Car>>` that I like to cache somewhere.

I don't want to use a static variable within the program for that, as if the application will run behind a load balancer, each instance might get different results from its own memory cache, and changes in one application will not take effect in the other.

So I was looking at [Redis & its Jedis client](https://medium.com/@karthikcsridhar/jedis-simple-guide-to-use-the-java-redis-library-18267221797b), but it seems like we can only cache items in a map with the type of `<String, String>` but not more complex items.

I also checked [Spring's @Cacheable annotation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/) option, but it seems like this complex object is not cached. See code sample below.

I'm wondering what should be the right approach to cache such complex items.

This is the code from the `@Cacheable` attempt:

```
    public class ComplexObject implements Serializable {... getters & setters ...}
```

In the service class:

```
    @Cacheable(value = "customerCars", key = "#customerName")
    public ComplexObject buildCoblexObject(String customerName, CarsRepository carRepository) {
    ...
    System.out.printlin("here") // printed every time method is called with the same customerName
    }
```

In the properties file: (both simple or redis are not caching the item):

```
spring.cache.type=simple
#spring.cache.type=redis
#spring.redis.host=localhost
#spring.redis.port=6379
```

In the application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
 public class MyApplication {....
```

Comment: Can't you just store the `List<Car>`, why would you want to store the keys?

Comment: _but it seems like this complex object is not cached_  Show the code that's not working, along with the cache's configuration.

Comment: @riorio Have you figured out the issue? I am having the same problem in caching complex map objects

Comment: Same problem here: I Use CrudRepository to save and load entities from redis. I have a Entity (@RedisHash) with a Map<String,List<String>> and the list items are stored as a single byte value but not as the String itself. In Redisson I think there is a special type for this use case but in spring data redis i haven´t found anything about that. Please help

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions would be to use a Redis hash. Its key would be a name of your complex object. Keys of its properties would be keys of the map. And `List<Car>` can be serialized with JSON.

If you often need to do iterations across all this map, you can instead serialize all `Map<String, List<Car>>` to JSON and store as a single key. But updates to this object would take significant time.

Comment: Yes, List<Car> can be serialized and saved with spring data redis when I use RedisHash on Class. But a Map<String, List<Car>> can not be saved right with redis, there is only stored one byte instead of the correct object.

Comment: @Holger I don't see the problem. Can you look here https://github.com/Imaskar/springcache ? I'm storing `Map<String, List<Car>>` just fine.

Comment: but you are not able to save it in redis as a RedisHash ;)